# plot of regression fitted values made using lines function in R just not turning right.

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have a big dataset with 100853 observations. I wish to determine the relationship between the 2 variables in my model i.e. log of per capita expenditure (ln_MPCE) and share of expenditure spent on food (w_food). To do this,I run a quadratic regression and a non-parametric regression. Then, I plot the data and the fitted values using the following code. However, the graphs are just not plotted right. Instead of getting 2 curves, I get a bunch of lines for both the regressions. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
model.par <- lm(w_food~ ln_MPCE+ I(ln_MPCE^2), data=share_efm_food_09)
summary(model.par) 
library(np) 
model.np <- npreg(w_food~ ln_MPCE, regtype="ll",bwmethod="cv.aic",data=share_efm_food_09)

pdf("food_Ln_MPCE_curve.pdf" , width=11, height=8)
plot(share_efm_food_09$ln_MPCE, share_efm_food_09$w_food, xlab="ln_MPCE",ylab="w_food", cex=.1)
lines(share_efm_food_09$ln_MPCE, fitted(model.np), lty=1, col="blue")
lines(share_efm_food_09$ln_MPCE, fitted(model.par), lty=1, col="red")
dev.off()
```

Comment: You should attempt to provide some sort of minimal, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that include sample input data so we can run the code to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the data are not sorted by the x-value, so that lines go back and forth, depending on where the next x-value happens to be in the current ordering of your data frame. Order the data frame by the x-value to get the line you were expecting.

Here's an example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + I(wt^2), data=mtcars)
```

Plot data in default order:

```
with(mtcars, plot(wt, mpg))
lines(mtcars$wt, fitted(m1), col="blue")
```

[image]

Add a prediction line with data sorted by `wt`:

```
newdat = data.frame(wt=mtcars$wt, mpgpred=fitted(m1))
newdat = newdat[order(newdat$wt),]

lines(newdat, col="red", lwd=4)
```

[image]

Rather than using `fitted`, you can also use `predict`, which will return predicted values from your model for any combination of values of the independent variables. You can then provide the original data frame sorted by `wt`:

```
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + I(wt^2), data=mtcars)

with(mtcars, plot(wt, mpg))
lines(mtcars$wt[order(mtcars$wt)], predict(m1, newdata=mtcars[order(mtcars$wt),]), col="red")
```

Comment: Thanks eipi, you rock :-)